# How do I use $pow in query?

Tags: pymongo

I have to find documents whose last access time is less than $24*2**n$ where n is a field in the database. I cannot get it to work so I constructed the following simplified version where I just focus on the case n=0 to show what I am doing and why I say its not working. According to me the following two codes should give the same result

```py
jsonstore.client[db][collection].find({'$where': 'this.last_access < 24'}).next()
```

and

```py
jsonstore.client[db][collection].find({'$where': 'this.last_access < 24*{$pow: [2,0]}'}).next()
```

as in the second code I am multiplying (trying to multiply) 24 by 2**0 which is just one. However, I do not get the same results (and infact get no responses for the second).

What am I doing wrong? I feel like there should be a command to replace {$pow: [2,0]} by something that evaluates it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is

```py
jsonstore.client[db][collection].find({'$where': 'this.last_access < 24*Math.pow(2,0)'})
```